# Discord.py How to make a coomand activate another command

Tags: discord.py

How can I code something that activate another command when one command is used

So when somebody use the ,start command it should do the things coded for the start command and then acttivate the ,hello command

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the command using [`Bot.get_command(name)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_command#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_command), and then invoke it using [`Context.invoke(command)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke).

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    # ... Do something here

    cmd = client.get_command("hello")
    await ctx.invoke(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send('The start command activated the hello command')

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
  await ctx.send('You started the start command!')
  
  await hello(ctx) #activates second command
```

As you can see you can activate the second command by doing `await hello(ctx)` (as they are asynchronous functions and need to be awaited) in the first command.